# display data labels column stacked epplus

Tags: epplus

I have a stacked column report and i need to show the label value inside each of the series, is this possible.  here is the code i have so far. It does look like barcharts have this option, not sure if i need to convert report to that type.

```
         chart.Title.Text = "Total Pipeline - Initiative Count by Release";
         chart.Title.Font.Size = 8;
         chart.SetPosition(45, 0, 3, 0);
         chart.SetSize(400, 300);
         chart.Legend.Add();
         chart.YAxis.MajorUnit = 10;
         var series1 = chart.Series.Add(Chartsheet.Cells["L23:Q23"], Chartsheet.Cells["L22:Q22"]);
         series1.HeaderAddress = new ExcelAddress("'Graphs'!K23");
         var series2 = chart.Series.Add(Chartsheet.Cells["L24:Q24"], Chartsheet.Cells["L22:Q22"]);
         series2.HeaderAddress = new ExcelAddress("'Graphs'!K24");
         chart.Legend.Position = eLegendPosition.Bottom;
         chart.YAxis.LabelPosition = eTickLabelPosition.NextTo;
         chart.XAxis.MajorTickMark = eAxisTickMark.Out;
         chart.XAxis.MinorTickMark = eAxisTickMark.None;
         chart.ShowDataLabelsOverMaximum = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

so i just forced a format of a barchart and i have the label option

```
    var chart = (OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart.ExcelBarChart) Chartsheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart", eChartType.ColumnStacked);
```